# Rectifying the Archimedean spirals with hypergeometric functions

Tags: definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function, arc-length

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3854217/357390) determines that the arc length of Fermat's spiral $r=k\sqrt\theta$ over $\theta\in[0,t]$ is given by
$$\int_0^tk\sqrt{\frac{1}{4\theta}+\theta}\,d\theta=k\sqrt t\ _2F_1\left(-\frac12,\frac14;\frac54;-4t^2\right)$$
On that answer I commented

> I challenge you to find the arc length of the lituus [$r=k\sqrt\theta$] using hypergeometric functions, like I did with elliptic integrals in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3856241/357390).

The reply came that the answerer already had the answer for that too. I then remembered that [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArchimedeanSpiral.html) states that for the general Archimedean spiral $r=k\theta^{1/n}$, if $n>0$ the arc length over $\theta\in[0,t]$ is
$$L_n(k,t)=kt^{1/n}\ _2F_1\left(-\frac12,\frac1{2n};1+\frac1{2n};-n^2t^2\right)$$
(If $n<0$ the spiral is unbounded both ways and the length over $\theta\in[a,b]$ where $0<a\le b$ is $L_n(k,a)-L_n(k,b)$).

It's all nice, but **how do we derive the hypergeometric expression for $L_n(k,t)$**? Please include a full derivation; don't just lean on the results from Mathematica or any other symbolic software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\theta=\frac x n$ which makes
$$\int \sqrt{r^2+(r')^2}\,d\theta=k \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}+1}\int x^{\frac{1}{n}-1}\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx $$
$$x^{\frac{1}{n}-1}\sqrt{x^2+1}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{m} x^{2 m+\frac{1}{n}-1}$$
$$\int x^{\frac{1}{n}-1}\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx =\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{m} }{2 m+\frac{1}{n}}x^{2 m+\frac{1}{n}}=n x^{\frac{1}{n}} \, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2 n};1+\frac{1}{2
   n};-x^2\right)$$

Comment: Congratulations. Your next task is to [rectify the Australian Broadcasting Corporation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3860886).

Comment: @ParclyTaxel. Be sure I tried ! After two hours (after my non-answer) I am giving up. Sorry for that. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Very nice solution. An alternative method is to recognize that the integral can be transformed into an incomplete beta function and thence to the hypergeometric function.